# Java Noob Creating a custom method to print array and calculate a duration

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have used this site to help me on many of my programming assignments before but I can not find anything similar to the issue that I am having now.

I am trying to first print the `myHobbies` array in the toString of the person class using the method `printHobby`, as well as calculate the total duration the the user has been doing the Hobby in `printDuration`. I am not sure why I can not get it to work and have been struggling with it for a while.

Any help would be appreciated. Here are my classes. This is my first time posting so if I am doing something wrong, please let me know.

```
//--------------------Person--------------------
public class Person {
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String address;
    int age;

    String hobbyText;
    private double durationH = 0;
    private double totalDuration = 0;

    Person(String f, String l, String a, int ag) {
        fName = f;
        lName = l;
        address = a;
        age = ag;
    }

    static Hobby[] myHobbies = new Hobby[5];

    static int i = 0;

    public static void setHobby(Hobby mh) {
        myHobbies[i] = mh;
        i++;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return fName + " " + lName + " " + address + " " + age + " "
                + printDuration() + " ";
    }

    public double printDuration() {
        for (int k = 0; k < myHobbies.length; k++)
            totalDuration += myHobbies[k].getDuration();
        return totalDuration;
    }

    public String printHobbies() {
        for (int j = 0; j < myHobbies.length; j++)
            hobbyText = myHobbies[j].toString();
        return hobbyText;
    }

}


//--------------------HobbyDriver--------------------
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HobbyDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hobby[] newHobby = {
                new Hobby("Comics", "09/25/2012", "The Comic Store", 1),
                new Hobby("Baseball", "09/30/2012", "Fenway Park", 3),
                new Hobby("Programming", "09/212/2012", "Home", 6),
                new Hobby("Board Games", "09/01/2012", "Tom's House", 3),
                new Hobby("Watching Dr. Who", "09/27/2012", "Home", 1) };

        String personChoice;
        Scanner hobbyScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {

            String fName;
            String lName;
            int age;
            String address;
            String hobbyName;
            String partDate;
            String location;
            double duration;
            int userHobby;
            String hobbyChoice;

            System.out.println("What is your first name?");

            fName = hobbyScan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your last name?");
            lName = hobbyScan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your address?");

            address = hobbyScan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your age?");

            age = hobbyScan.nextInt();
            hobbyScan.nextLine();

            do {

                System.out
                        .println("What hobbies would you like to do?\n"
                                + "choose between     Comics(0)\nBaseball(1)\nProgramming(2)\nBoard Games(3)\nWatching Dr.Who(4)\n"
                                + "\nEnter    the name of the hobby and then press enter");

                userHobby = hobbyScan.nextInt();
                hobbyScan.nextLine();

                System.out
                        .println("Would you like to add another hobby? (enter yes/no)");

                hobbyChoice = hobbyScan.nextLine();

                Person.setHobby(newHobby[userHobby]);

            } while (hobbyChoice.equals("yes"));

            System.out
                    .println("Would you like to add another person? (enter yes/no)");
            personChoice = hobbyScan.nextLine();

            int i = 0;

            Person[] newPerson = new Person[5];
            newPerson[i] = new Person(fName, lName, address, age);

            System.out.println(newPerson[i].toString());

            i++;

        } while (personChoice.equals("yes"));

    }

}




//--------------------Hobby--------------------
public class Hobby {

    private String hobbyName;
    private String partDate;
    private String location;
    private double duration;

    Hobby(String h, String p, String l, double d) {
        hobbyName = h;
        partDate = p;
        location = l;
        duration = d;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return hobbyName + " " + partDate + " " + location + " " + duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(double d) {
        d = duration;
    }

    public double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say it isn't working, do you mean it won't compile, it throws a runtime exception, or it produces the wrong results? If it's the wrong results, which results does it give and what would you expect it to give?

Comment: Just a note: choose good names for your methods. `printHobbies()` doesn't print anything. So its name should be something like `getHobbiesAsString()`.

Comment: Tip: its common practice that integer/counter used in loop iterations is called `i`. Also variables declared in methods are local, and it is safe to name reference the same in few methods, so your *for loops* in both `printDuration()` and `printHobbies()` can look like `for (int i = 0; i < myHobbies.length; i++)`.

Comment: Please tag as 'Homework'. Also, it is considered rude to post your entire program as-is. You should extract the bits that don't work, and boil down your question to something simple that can be understood quickly. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html is a great reference that is worth a quick read.

Comment: Actually, just realized that "Homework" has been deprecated. My bad. The other point above still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the following:

```
public String printHobbies() {
    for (int j = 0; j < myHobbies.length; j++)
        hobbyText = myHobbies[j].toString();    
    return hobbyText;
}
```

First, you overwrite your string in each loop. Write

```
hobbyText += myHobbies[j].toString();
```

Second, You will get a NPE if you don't add 5 Hobbies, because every item in the array is null at the beginning.

So you will have to check if myHobbies[j] is not null:

```
public String printHobbies() {
    for (int j = 0; j < myHobbies.length; j++) {
        if(myHobbies[j] != null) {
            hobbyText += myHobbies[j].toString();
        }
    }  
    return hobbyText;
}
```

You also may want to have a look at Collections: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Answer (score 1):

There are few bugs which may cause an issue in your code, it depends on current usage.

1. You do not reset the total duration, which means, that it returns proper result only after the first invocation. Otherwise it is multiplied by the number of invocations.

   ```
   public double printDuration() {
       for (int k = 0; k < myHobbies.length; k++)
           totalDuration += myHobbies[k].getDuration();
       return totalDuration;
   }
   ```
2. You use the simple array with the fix size 5. It means, that if you add more than 5 hobbies, it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
3. You call `toString()` method on all hobbies in the array nevertheless they were set. The arrays are initialized to `null` by default, which means, that if you set less than 5 hobbies, you try to call it on `null` which throws `NullPointerException`.

   ```
   public String printHobbies() {
       for (int j = 0; j < myHobbies.length; j++)
           hobbyText += myHobbies[j].toString();
       return hobbyText;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for you help. It was that I wasn't making sure that it wasn't null. Next time I post I will also be able to make sure that it is formatted better.